# EF migrate.exe does not see my code-based migration files

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-framework-5, entity-framework-migrations

We have a situation, where a team of developers started working on a project with EF code first and originally the automatic migrations were enabled. Now we need to sort out the mess, turn off automatic migrations, reset everyone's migrations history and 'start anew', forcing all developers to use manual, code-based migrations from now on.

I have been following this answer to clear the migrations history (which worked so far):
[EF - Moving from AutomaticMigrations to Manual Migrations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20085245/ef-moving-from-automaticmigrations-to-manual-migrations/20108929#20108929)

In the meantime we would like to automatise the application of the code-based migrations in the deployment process.

For that, I have been playing around with migrate.exe as described here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/data/jj618307.aspx

We have a DAL project that hold all the data objects and deals with migration.

1. I have copied migration.exe from /packages/EntityFramework.5.0.0 to DAL/bin/Debug.
2. I have updated my DB to the latest, then cleared my migrations history table.
3. I changed a StringLength attribute in one of my models and run `add-migration test`.

Now, I have exactly 2 code-based migrations in my DAL/Migrations folder: one for the initial create, and one for modifying the column that I've changed. (they both have their .resx and .Designer.cs brothers)

**I am trying to run migrate.exe to apply the last migration** (test) like this:

```
migrate.exe MyApp.DAL.dll /startupConfigurationFile="..\..\app.config"
```

It runs, then it prints 
**No pending code-based migrations.**
And then fails, because it wants to run an automatic migrations, and fails, because it is turned off. (which is ok, 'cause I don't want automatic migrations)

For some reason migrate.exe **does not see my code-based migration files**.
What am I doing wrong?

(If I try to apply the same migration from PM console, that works)